# Extract version identifier from the url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the folowing urls in JavaScript:

```
bryntum.com/examples-1.2.3/advanced/advanced.html
bryntum.com/doc/1.2.3/foo/bar.html
cdn.sencha.io/ext-3.4.0/ext-all-debug.js
cdn.sencha.io/ext-3.4.0-beta-1/ext-all.js
cdn.sencha.io/extjs-4.1.0-rc-1/ext-all-debug.js
bryntum.com/examplesfor/extjs-4.1.1/foo/bar.html
bryntum.com/library/extjs-4.1.2/ext-all-debug.js
bryntum.com/library/extjs-10.11.21/ext-all-debug.js
bryntum.com/library/extjs-4.1.2/ext-all-this-is-not-ext.js
```

I need to extract extjs/ext vesion number with regex: after 'extjs-' or after 'ext-' and up to next '/'. But URLs potentially can point to some other resource, in which case the RegExp should not match

Comment: You should mention the platform you're using. Regex has subtle differences in different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

For .net world, the following should work:

```
ext(js)?\-(?<ver>\d[^/]+)(?:/)
```

The named group will give you the precise version number too.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex flavor you're using supports lookarounds, this should suit your needs:

```
(?<=ext-|extjs-).+?(?=/)
```

While the above regex is possibly to much permissive, the following one is more specific (matching the possible formats I guessed from your OP):

```
(?<=ext-|extjs-)\d+([.]\d+){0,2}(-(beta|rc)-\d+)?
```